# Windows Forms UserControl overrides not being called

Tags: wpf, winforms, c++-cli, user-controls, onpaint

I am creating a Windows Forms control derived from UserControl to be embedded in a WPF app. I have generally followed the procedures given in [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOpenGL.aspx?display=Print).

```
public ref class CTiledImgViewControl : public UserControl
{
...

virtual void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs^ e ) override;

...
};
```

And in my CPP file:

```
void CTiledImgViewControl::OnPaint( PaintEventArgs^ e )
{
    UserControl::OnPaint(e);
    // do something interesting...
}
```

Everything compiles and runs, however the OnPaint method is never getting called.

Any ideas of things to look for? I've done a lot with C++, but am pretty new to WinForms and WPF, so it could well be something obvious...

Comment: I have updated my answer after discovering a similar problem in my own work. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnPaint` won't normally get called in a `UserControl` unless you set the appropriate style when it is constructed using the `SetStyle` method. You need to set the `UserPaint` style to true for the `OnPaint` to get called.

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles::UserPaint, true);
```

#### Update

I recently encountered this issue myself and went digging for an answer. I wanted to perform some calculations during a paint (to leverage the unique handling of paint messages) but I wasn't always getting a call to `OnPaint`.

After digging around with Reflector, I discovered that `OnPaint` is only called if the clipping rectangle of the corresponding `WM_PAINT` message is not empty. My `UserControl` instance had a child control that filled its entire client region and therefore, clipped it all. This meant that the clipping rectangle was empty and so no `OnPaint` call.

I worked around this by overriding `WndProc` and adding a handler for `WM_PAINT` directly as I couldn't find another way to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, in case anyone is interested. It was because my WinForms control was embedded in a ViewBox. I changed it to a grid and immediately started getting paint events. I guess when asking questions about WPF, you should always include the XAML in the question!